# SSRS remove space between rectangles

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with three rectangles and a tablix inside each, I'm using the rectangles to create page breaks so when I export to excel I have three named tabs for each tablix, however because I cannot eliminate the space totally between rectangles row one in tabs two and three in excel are blank rows.
Is there anyway of removing the space totally?

Comment: please attach screenshot for better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are putting the page break at the end of the rectangle. Any space after that will show as a row before the next table.

Put the page break at the **Start** of your 2nd and 3rd tables.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post I tried your recommendation too and that works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Select all and select Remove Vertical Spacing in tool bar. Doh